# Can't publish custom type posts that don't support title and editor, instead they're saved as draft

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor, publish, post-status, draft

I’m developing a plugin that registers custom post types without support for title and editor. I’ve been working on this project for a couple of months now and when I began (WP version 6.3.1), it used to be the case that when I clicked “Publish”, these posts were saved with the title “Auto Draft”, a name similar to “auto-draft-123”, and the status “publish”. Now (WP version 6.4.3), when I click “Publish”, these type of posts are saved with a status of “draft”, without a name, and it’s impossible to change the status to “publish” without updating the value directly in the database (i.e. using Adminer) or taking some steps that I will describe below.

To replicate this issue, do the following:

1. Register a custom post type without support for title nor the editor.
2. Add a meta box to the custom post type with one or more custom fields.
3. Create a new post with the registered CPT.
4. Click publish.

The environment I’m working on is:

- WP version 6.4.3
- OS: Windows 10 Home Edition
- WP is run on Local by Flywheel version 8.2.1

These are the troubleshooting steps that I’ve taken so far:

- Created a new site on Local with zero plugins besides the one I’m developing, restricting the behavior of the plugin to that of only registering the CPT with no support for title nor the editor. The theme that was used for testing is Twenty-twenty-four.
- Erased browser cookies (Brave) and cleared the cache.
- Turned off and on the computer (just in case).
- I installed the previous version of WordPress in which I am 100% sure that my plugin used to work, which is 6.3.1. I did this in Local.
- I installed the previous version of Local in which I am 100% sure that my plugin used to work, which is 7.1.2.
- I setup a testing server with XAMPP, I manually downloaded the WP version 6.3.1 and installed it there.
- I tried with Chrome, Firefox, and Edge (besides Brave).
- The behavior in all the different environments was the same, the CPT Post with no support for title no editor is saved as “draft” when I click “Publish” and it’s impossible to change the status to “publish” by clicking “Publish”.

I currently don’t have access to a different Computer or OS.

There are some things that I found out though:

- When I click “Publish”, the parameter `post_status` is sent as “draft”.
- If I add title and editor support to the CPT, but set `show_in_rest` as false, once the post is saved as “draft”, and add a title and some text to the editor, the post isn’t published when I click “Publish”, the status “draft” remains.
- If I set `show_in_rest` as true, once the post is saved as “draft”, then the post can be published, changing its status to “publish” once I click “Publish” (with title and editor support).

The only way in which I can change the status to “publish” once the post is saved as “draft” without adding support for the editor and not showing in rest is by doing this:

1. Set the status to “Pending Review” from the dropdown in the submit box in the post editing screen.
2. On the list of posts, click “Quick Edit” and choose the status of “Scheduled” from the dropdown menu.
3. Click “Update”.

I’m doing all of this using the Admin user.

I guess it may have to do with some recent update in Gutenberg that I’m not aware of, given that I tried an old version of WP (6.3.1) and the most recent one (6.4.3) that comes bundled with Local, and in both cases, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough investigation, I identified the root cause of the issue.

**TL;DR**: A bug in my JavaScript code was causing the post form to be submitted without the necessary `publish` parameter. Consequently, WordPress interpreted the request as an attempt to save a draft. I resolved the issue by updating the code to include the `publish` parameter upon successful validation of the post's meta data.

**Detailed Explanation:**

During post submission, the value of the clicked submit button is transmitted as a parameter. For instance, the "Publish" button's value is sent as `publish: Publish`, indicating to WordPress the intended action. If the `publish` parameter is received and not empty, the post is published.

Delving further, when a post hasn't been published yet, the `post_status` parameter defaults to `draft`. This value is transmitted with the new post regardless of the button clicked for submission. If the `publish` parameter is present and non-empty, the `post_status` value changes to `publish`, marking the post as published in the database. Otherwise, the post remains in draft status.

Upon analyzing the submitted data, I noticed that the `publish` parameter was missing despite clicking the corresponding button.

Unbeknownst to me, I had implemented JavaScript validation code several months ago to validate post meta data before submission. However, I failed to test this validation logic before moving on to other parts of the plugin. Thus, while validation was indeed preventing form submission, the `publish` parameter wasn't added upon successful validation.